# mappingmongoconverter readMap

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using SpringBoot with MongoDB, I have a document as it shows in the image below.

[document in mongodb(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oROkX.png)

And I mapped to a java class:

```
@Document(collection = "instrument")
public abstract class Instrument extends BaseMongoEntity<String> {

    @NotEmpty
    private String feedProviderId;

    @NotEmpty
    private String code;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    private Map<String, Object> instrumentData;

    private Map<String, Object> commonInfo;

    private List<InstrumentHistoricalData> historicalData;

    private List<DelayedInstrumentData> delayedData;

    private String market;

    // Getters, setters, builders, etc.    

}
```

Of course, the instrumentData field contains lots of data, but for the sake of the argument I just wrote those two in the document showed.
So my problem is that I can`t convert the NOW_PRICE to BigDecimal. I can write it with with no problem, BigDecimal to Decimal128, but not the other way around.

I have configured both reader and writer as show below:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                new BigDecimalDecimal128Converter(),
                new Decimal128BigDecimalConverter()
        ));

    }

    @WritingConverter
    private static class BigDecimalDecimal128Converter implements 
            Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128> {

        @Override
        public Decimal128 convert(@NonNull BigDecimal source) {
            return new Decimal128(source);
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    private static class Decimal128BigDecimalConverter implements 
            Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal> {

        @Override
        public BigDecimal convert(@NonNull Decimal128 source) {
            return source.bigDecimalValue();
        }

    }

}
```

So checking the MappingMongoConverter.class, I noted this:

```
protected Map<Object, Object> readMap(TypeInformation<?> type, Bson bson, ObjectPath path) {

    Assert.notNull(bson, "Document must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(path, "Object path must not be null!");

    Class<?> mapType = typeMapper.readType(bson, type).getType();

    TypeInformation<?> keyType = type.getComponentType();
    TypeInformation<?> valueType = type.getMapValueType();

    Class<?> rawKeyType = keyType != null ? keyType.getType() : null;
    Class<?> rawValueType = valueType != null ? valueType.getType() : null;

    Map<String, Object> sourceMap = asMap(bson);
    Map<Object, Object> map = CollectionFactory.createMap(mapType, rawKeyType, sourceMap.keySet().size());

    if (!DBRef.class.equals(rawValueType) && isCollectionOfDbRefWhereBulkFetchIsPossible(sourceMap.values())) {
        bulkReadAndConvertDBRefMapIntoTarget(valueType, rawValueType, sourceMap, map);
        return map;
    }

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : sourceMap.entrySet()) {

        if (typeMapper.isTypeKey(entry.getKey())) {
            continue;
        }

        Object key = potentiallyUnescapeMapKey(entry.getKey());

        if (rawKeyType != null && !rawKeyType.isAssignableFrom(key.getClass())) {
            key = conversionService.convert(key, rawKeyType);
        }

        Object value = entry.getValue();
        TypeInformation<?> defaultedValueType = valueType != null ? valueType : ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT;

        if (value instanceof Document) {
            map.put(key, read(defaultedValueType, (Document) value, path));
        } else if (value instanceof BasicDBObject) {
            map.put(key, read(defaultedValueType, (BasicDBObject) value, path));
        } else if (value instanceof DBRef) {
            map.put(key, DBRef.class.equals(rawValueType) ? value
                    : readAndConvertDBRef((DBRef) value, defaultedValueType, ObjectPath.ROOT, rawValueType));
        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            map.put(key, readCollectionOrArray(valueType != null ? valueType : ClassTypeInformation.LIST,
                    (List<Object>) value, path));
        } else {
            map.put(key, getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(value, rawValueType));
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

So it's only asking if the value is instance of Document, BasicDBObject, DBRef or List. Otherwise it assumes the value is already mapped, which is not, because it's a numeric value and that possibility it's not being considered.

Am I missing something? Is there a workoaround for this problem? Thank you!

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you dig down into `getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(…)` you see that we check the `CustomConversionInstance` for whether there is a conversion registered. I can only assume there's something wrong in your configuration but there's nothing terribly off I can see. Do you have an example project to share that I can play with?

Comment: //Thank you for your answer, i will try to make an example project. In regards to your answer,It will not reach to that statement, it returns through the first one, because the target is Object and isAssignable() returns true  -> private Object getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(@Nullable Object value, @Nullable Class<?> target) {

  if (value == null || target == null || ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(target, value)) {
   return value;
  }

  if (conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(value.getClass(), target)) {
   return conversionService.convert(value, target);
  }